# Missing sbt/boot/ directory in new play-2.1.1 installation. Playframework installation on Linux Mint 14

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.1, linux-mint

I'm trying to install the Play! Framework on a Linux Mint box, but I'm having a hard time getting **play** going. After the installation, I'm getting folliwing error message when I type play help at the command line:

```
    $ play help
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/play-2.1.1/framework/sbt/boot/update.log (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:171)
    at java.io.FileWriter.<init>(FileWriter.java:90)
    at xsbt.boot.Update.<init>(Checks.java:51)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.update(Launch.scala:275)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$$anonfun$jnaLoader$1.apply(Launch.scala:120)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:108)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.jnaLoader$2f324eef(Launch.scala:115)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch.<init>(Launch.scala:94)
    at xsbt.boot.Launcher$.apply(Launch.scala:290)
    at xsbt.boot.Launch$.apply(Launch.scala:16)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.runImpl(Boot.scala:31)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot$.main(Boot.scala:20)
    at xsbt.boot.Boot.main(Boot.scala)
Error during sbt execution: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/play-2.1.1/framework/sbt/boot/update.log (No such file or directory)
```

As can be seen, play is installed in the /home directory. Content of .bashrc file is as follows:

```
$ cat ~/.bashrc
export PATH=""/home/play-2.1.1:$PATH""
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_12
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
export CLASSPATH=$JAVA_HOME/lib/dt.jar:.:$JAVA_HOME/lib/tools.jar:$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

I wonder if I've left out something during the installation process that accounts for the difficulty in getting play up and running. Will appreciate helpfull hints and advise. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have write permissions on the Play framework path.  You will get this error if you do not.